# Unable to call function in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am new in CodeIgniter now I am creating a site. an Admin can view all records after login but unfortunately, the target URL shows 404 Page Not Found. I am using temple(header n footer) for a menu.
here is my header.php

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarColor01">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto" >
<?php if(!$this->session->userdata('logged_in')) : ?>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>users/login">Login</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>users/register">Register</a></li>
      <?php endif; ?>
      <?php if($this->session->userdata('logged_in')) : ?>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>posts">List Item</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>posts/create">Create Post</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>users/logout">Logout</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>admin">Admin</a></li>
      <?php endif; ?>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

When I click the admin menu then it should be goto Admin Controller and call index function for cofirmation i put echo and die but it shows 404 error. here is my Admin Controller

```
<?php
class Admin extends CI_Controller{
    public function index(){    
        echo "Reach here"; die;
        if (!$this->session->userdata('logged_in')) {
            redirect('users/login');
        }
?>
```

Thanks in advance for assistance.

Comment: how you call the  controller?

Comment: What is your default controller?

Comment: is this file redirect('users/login'); is in user folder

Comment: default controller is $route['default_controller'] = 'pages/view';

Comment: @prasanna puttaswamy if the user doesn't login & direct access the url then redirect to login page. but i am just checking & use die before call this function

Comment: After login what was the url for redirection?ie, what is your form_open action?

Comment: @Robert after login i use $route['posts/index'] = 'posts/index';

Comment: then you want to write all your code inside posts controllers index function
<?php
class Posts extends CI_Controller{
    public function index(){    
        echo "Reach here"; die;
        if (!$this->session->userdata('logged_in')) {
            redirect('users/login');
        }
?>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Put your admin link like this :**

as `Admin` is not your default `controller` and you not set your route for admin

Put your `admin` link like this

```
<li class="nav-item">
  <a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo base_url('admin/index'); ?>">Admin</a> 
</li>
```

but if you want to do like this :

```
<li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo base_url('admin'); ?>">Admin</a> 
</li>
```

then set `route.php` like this :

```
$route['admin'] = 'admin/index';
```

And controller :

```
<?php
class Admin extends CI_Controller{
    public function index(){    
        echo "Reach here"; die;
        if (!$this->session->userdata('logged_in')) {
            redirect('users/login');
        }
?>
```

Comment: it works but don't know why it doesn't call without index even i use same for post controller

Comment: if you want to work your url you have to set route.php for admin controller

Comment: Ok Thank you Pradeep

Answer (score 0):

Please use parent construct and after you can do your way.

```
public function __construct() {
            parent :: __construct();

            $this->load->model(array('restaurants_m', 'categories_m', 'cities_m', 'customers_m', 'states_m', 'orders_m', 'delivery_boys_m'));

            $this->load->library(array('email'));
            $this->load->helper('url');
    }
```